# Major issues/ Notes for upgrading GeoServer 2.10.0 to 2.19.x / 2.20.x. It's a platform independent installation in Windows (no Tomcat)

Tags: geoserver

The current version which we use is GeoServer 2.10.0, which is a platform-independent installation. We want to upgrade this version to near latest version 2.19.x or 2.20.x.
The plan is to take backup of data_dir of 2.10.0. Install a new version on a different port, test it with old version data_dir, if all OK, uninstall 2.10.0 and install the new version on the required port again.

Is it recommended to Jump from 2.10 to 2.19/2.20?
Are there any major concerns to keep track of?
Is there a better plan to upgrade/ Jump from 2.10 to 2.19/2.20?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not recommended but it's worth a try. If it doesn't work try the same procedure in 2 steps and if that doesn't work try it in 3 and so on until you catch up.

In future don't leave it so long to make upgrades.

Comment: Thanks,
So by 2 or 3 steps, you mean. 2.10 -> 2.15 ->2.20 or 2.10 -> 2.14 ->2.17 ->2.20.